# Check given input is delimited by : 3 times only

Tags: regex

How do i validate the input string is in `xxx:xxx:xxx` format. I do not need to validate the number of characters delimited by `:`. I just need to make sure there are exactly 3 blocks delimited by `:` in the given input.

Input can contain any character including space but not 3 white spaces only delimited by :

This is how my regex looks like:

```
\w{3}:\w{3}:\w{4}$
```

The problem with this regex is that it checks for the format `xxx-xxx-xxxx` and invalidates everything else. I need to remove that constraint.

Valid inputs can be:

```
some:word that:is given by the user
a valid input:also:looks like this
and it:can:be this
```

Invalid input:

```
 : : 
this:is invalid
this:is:also:invalid
this is invalid
```

***If you can explain the regex, i will highly appreciate that***

Comment: That's because you don't have the start anchor and in matches such part at the end of strings with more than 3 `:`. `^\w{3}:\w{3}:\w{4}$`

Comment: Can any of the blocks be empty? E.g., what is the status of `a::b`?

Comment: no. it cannot be blank of have only white space(s)

Comment: What langauge are you using? It might be easier to simply split the string on `:`, count the resulting fields, and verify that at least one (or all?) of them is more then just whitespace.

Comment: @chepner:Its a third party tool that only accepts regex as validation input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
^(?![\s:]*$)[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+$
```

or a VERBOSE version:

```
    ^   (?![\s:]*$)    [^:]+   :    [^:]+   :   [^:]+     $
  start  no empty      1st          2nd         3rd     end
```

Here is a [WORKING regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF3rB5/1).

The `^` matches the start of string, `[^:]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `:` and `:` matches a colon. `$` matches the end of string.

The `(?![\s:]*$)` lookahead will prevent matches where blocks are all empty.

**Update**

To make the match fail if ***any*** of the blocks is empty, add the lookahead restrictions before each:

```
^(?!\s*:)[^:]+:(?!\s*:)[^:]+:(?!\s*$)[^:]+$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF3rB5/2)

Comment: This still allows all spaces.

Comment: Now that you have changed the regex, I agree. Flipped vote.

Comment: I was updating the answer when you downvoted. It was already correct then.

Comment: It allows below formats which are invalid
 : :invalid format
 :invalid:invalid format
invalid format: :invalid format

Comment: Ok, just a sec. You just need to make sure each of the block is not empty.

Comment: I used `\n` inside character classes in the demo since I am using a multiline string. You do not need them if you use the regex against a single-line standalon string.

Comment: @RubenPirotte: To insert code in a comment, enclose it with `\``. And if you need to use a `\`` inside the code, just escape it with ``\``.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on @WiktorStribiżew 's answer. This change would make it better if there was a need for a variable amount of groups, as we would only have to change the `{2}` to the number of groups needed -1.

```
^(?![\s:]*$)([^:\n]+:){2}[^:\n]+$
```

**UPDATE 1**

To tackle following issue:

> this regex does not make sure if none of the parts is empty

After some tweaking I came with following update, still making it possible to use a variable amount of groups:

```
^(((\s*[^:\s]+)|(\s+[^:\s]+)|([^:\s]+\s+)|([^:\s]+\s*))+(\s)*:){2}(?!\s*$)[^:]+$
```

Comment: The point is that this regex does not make sure if none of the parts is empty.